# Recursively work through an array in php to modify the leaf

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I hve the following array

```
$array = array(
  array(
    "name" => "Jacky O'Macky",
    "groups" => array (
      array (
        "Joseph O'Brien",
        "Jenna Williams"
      ),
      array (
        "Shaq O'Neil",
        "John Fabio"
      )
    )
  ),
  array(
    "name" => "Nate O'Grady",
    "groups" => array (
      array (
        "Joseph O'Brien",
        "Jenna Williams"
      ),
      array (
        "Shaq O'Neil",
        "John Fabio"
      )
    )
  )
);
```

I would like to go through each array and use the `htmlspecialchars()` to handle the names with apostrophe's and keep the same multi-dimensionally array structure.

Here is what I have so far

```
function htmlentities_array($array)
{
  if (is_array($array))
  {
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {
      if (is_string($value))
      {
        $array[$key] = htmlspecialchars($value);
      }
      else
      {
        $array[$key] = htmlentities_array($value);
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    $array = htmlspecialchars($array);
  }

  return $array;
}
```

I am calling this via `$array = htmlentities_array(array)`. It seems to only work on the first level.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go

```
array_walk_recursive ($array, function(&$v,$k){
  $v = htmlspecialchars($v, ENT_QUOTES);
});

print_r($array);
```

Output

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Jacky O&#039;Macky
        [groups] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Joseph O&#039;Brien
                        [1] => Jenna Williams
                    )

                [1] => Array
    ....
```

Simple...

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/61eb12a9da2269dc32ad23cb279dae0e7886ea4f)

Comment: Amazing! Thank you @ArtisticPhoenix. For arrays that I am pulling out of a database with all sorts of different types (strings, numbers, etc.) would you suggest doing this against the fully fetched array? Any drawbacks?

Comment: It knows the difference between arrays and other types, because it automatically feeds an array back in.  Or recursively walks them, so it only runs the callback against non array types.  Probably the only type you need worry about is objects, which is probably an easily predictable case. INTs, and other numbers shouldn't matter with htmlspecialchars, php will just convert them to strings.

Comment: The trick is the `&$v` the `&` is pass by reference, if you didn't know that.  That makes it so when you do `$v = something` it updates the original.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the &$v reference, I need to research that more as I'm not clear on what a pass by reference is and what it would be used for, but I'll get it once I work through it.

Regarding the recursive array, I do have a few objects (where instead of a key it's a named object - example: array("keyname"=>"value"), what issues should i anticipate with feeding that in?

Thanks again, that solution was elegant.

Comment: None, I mean class objects (like an instance of DateTime class). Reference is basically the opposite of copy, so instead of creating a new array it works on the same array.  Without that `&` the function (Callback) arguments are copies, so if you change them you are changing a copy and it's not reflected in the original.

Comment: Thanks! A follow-up question to this. I have created two recursive arrays, one for htmlspecialchars(), when pulling data from MySQL and displaying on the front-end, and another for entering data in using $mysqli->real_escape_string(). 

My issue is that sometimes the escaped array (using real_escape_string()) is used then in json_encode, which double escapes, and seems to throw an error and not to be entered into SQL. Any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks again

Comment: don't use `real_escape_string` use Prepared Statements instead